# Adding SASS to style tags in .vue files in a Vue 3 Project

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuejs3

I have a Vue 3 Project with some .scss files in assets directory, which works perfectly fine (There is a **main.scss** file which builds a new **main.css** everytime I save the main.scss file, using an extension: "Live Sass Compiler"). But when I try to add SASS in one of my vue files by adding **lang="scss"** to the "style" tag, it doesn't work and gives me an error. So, then I tryied to install **sass** and **sass-loader** with **npm**, it still gives me an error when running the app.

- Node version: **v16.15.0**
- NPM version: **8.11.0**
- PNPM version: **6.14.5**
- List item

#### Here is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "post-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "8": "0.0.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "date-fns": "^2.23.0",
    "firebase": "^8.10.0",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.7.1",
    "sass": "^1.67.0",
    "uniqid": "^5.4.0",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0-0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "^4.5.13",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^12.1.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

#### Component.vue

```html
<style lang="scss"></style>
```

After adding the line of code above and adding some SASS styles in it, there is the next error in the **terminal** that I was talking about previously when running `npm run serve`:

```
> post-app@0.1.0 serve C:\users\aligu\desktop\post-app
> vue-cli-service serve

Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
  npx browserslist@latest --update-db
  Why you should do it regularly: https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating
 INFO  Starting development server...
13% building 27/28 modules 1 active ...oader\dist\cjs.js??ref--0-0!C:\Users\aligu\Desktop\Post-App\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\vue-loader-v16\dist\index.js??ref--0-1!C:\users\aligu\desktop\post-app\src\App.vueC:\Users\aligu\Desktop\Post-App\node_modules\webpack\lib\Dependency.js:353
                throw new Error(
                ^

Error: module property was removed from Dependency (use compilation.moduleGraph.updateModule(dependency, module) instead)
    at ProvidedDependency.set (C:\Users\aligu\Desktop\Post-App\node_modules\webpack\lib\Dependency.js:353:9)
    at iterationDependencies (C:\Users\aligu\Desktop\Post-App\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:940:21)
    at C:\Users\aligu\Desktop\Post-App\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:950:8
    at C:\Users\aligu\Desktop\Post-App\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:409:6
    at C:\Users\aligu\Desktop\Post-App\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:155:13
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\aligu\Desktop\Post-App\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:14:1)
    at C:\Users\aligu\Desktop\Post-App\node_modules\case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin\index.js:178:9
    at C:\Users\aligu\Desktop\Post-App\node_modules\case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin\index.js:125:7
    at C:\Users\aligu\Desktop\Post-App\node_modules\case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin\index.js:125:7
    at CaseSensitivePathsPlugin.fileExistsWithCase (C:\Users\aligu\Desktop\Post-App\node_modules\case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin\index.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\aligu\Desktop\Post-App\node_modules\case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin\index.js:118:10
    at CaseSensitivePathsPlugin.getFilenamesInDir (C:\Users\aligu\Desktop\Post-App\node_modules\case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin\index.js:52:5)
    at CaseSensitivePathsPlugin.fileExistsWithCase (C:\Users\aligu\Desktop\Post-App\node_modules\case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin\index.js:101:8)
    at C:\Users\aligu\Desktop\Post-App\node_modules\case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin\index.js:118:10
    at Array.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aligu\Desktop\Post-App\node_modules\case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin\index.js:72:5)
    at Storage.finished (C:\Users\aligu\Desktop\Post-App\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
 ERROR  Command failed with exit code 1.
```

[My codebox example](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/Ali-Guliyev/Post-App/master?file=/src/App.vue:1,1).

Comment: Please provide a *runnable* [mcve] using codesandbox.io or a similar service.

Comment: can you try node-sass once and let me know

Comment: @SureshKumarGangumallla, you mean I should try installing node-sass dependency and then it will work?

Comment: @tao, I added the link to the bottom of the post, but it looks terribly big, but you can open my app tho now.

Comment: @AliGuliyev It seems like problem with webpack, From package-lock I found, webpack  "version": "4.46.0" installed by @vue/cli-service  "version": "4.5.13", Can you try downgrading vue/cli-service version to other version meanwhile I will drill into issue

Answer (score 0):

Resolved scss issue by upgrading vue-cli-services packages to latest version.You can fetch latest one from [here](https://github.com/suresh-gangumalla/Post-App)

Comment: I cloned this forked repo, but I still get some errors when running npm run serve (btw if you have discord can you please send me your name so that we can talk much more easier)

Comment: my discord name is guliyev007

Comment: can you please remove the my Repo from your account? I made it private so that no one will fork it again, but can you please remove it? I don't want anyone to access my source code anymore.

Comment: Done @AliGuliyev

Comment: Appreciate it .

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the error appears when these styles rules are empty.